# Java Exception getMessage() returns null

Tags: java, error-handling, response

While trying to Deserialize a JSON into an object, I catch a SAXParsingException which looks like this. Writing out of memory so it might not be 100% correct, but the idea is the same.

```
try {
      validator.validate(source);
      return Response.ok(jsonResponse).build();
    } 
     catch (SAXParseException format) {
       String exceptionStr = format.getMessage();
       exceptionStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(exceptionStr);
       return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exceptionStr).build();
    }
```

However getMessage() returns null. However if I just return

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(format).build();
```

then it returns a stack trace looking like this (I've cropped out most of the stack trace as it's very long)

```
   {
"cause": {
    "cause": {
        "stackTrace": [

            {
                "methodName": "run",
                "fileName": "Thread.java",
                "lineNumber": 745,
                "className": "java.lang.Thread",
                "nativeMethod": false
            }
        ],
        "lineNumber": 0,
        "columnNumber": 0,
        "message": "cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Request' is not complete. One of '{\"blahblahblah":echoData, \"blahblahblah":schemeCode}' is expected.",
        "localizedMessage": "cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Request' is not complete. One of '{blahablah":echoData, \"blahbblahblah":schemeCode}' is expected."
    },
```

So why getMessage() is returning null if there is a message attached to the exception?

Comment: Notice the `"cause"` elements. It's not the `SAXParseException` that has the message but one of the exceptions in the causal chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialization object you are getting come from exception [cause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXException.html#getCause()) , the message is still empty. Java exception as SAXParseException usually contains the message field and `cause exception`,  in the case was another exception the origin of the problem.

You may be interested in the use `org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage/getRootCauseStackTrace` which found the root cause message (as in your example is also possible that your cause has a cause itself)

Comment: Also, in such cases, it might a good idea to check the exception propagation, and fix it so that the 'message' is not lost on the top level.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by others, I needed

String exceptionStr = format.getException().getCause().getMessage();

As my 'Message' was nested in other elements.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the solution you mentioned, in such cases, it might be a good idea to check the exception propagation, and fix it so that the 'message' is not lost on the top level (i.e. if you have control of the underlying exception handling)